# Excel Returning how many values

Tags: excel

I have the following list:

```
  Column1 | Column2
1 Test1   | 3
2 Test2   | 2
3 Test1   | 3
4 Test1   | 5
5 Test2   | 1
```

How can I get the total from column2 where column1 = test1

```
Ex:  
Test1 = 11
Test2 = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx). For ex.

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5,"Test1",B1:B5)
```

Answer (score 0):

As bdhar has mentioned, SUMIF will do what you want.

Alternatively, if the values in Column1 cannot be predicted in advance, you can use a Pivot Table.